# Create an image that will fill two rows using the Foundation Framework

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have been into Web Development just for a little while and some topics are still confusing for me.  I have found that if I take one webpage every week and try to replicate how they created the website, then I will learn a lot from that experience.

This week I was looking for a website to reverse engineer and I came across this one: 
http://www.nevrisfurs.com

I learned that using tables for layout it's a pretty bad idea and bad practice. Some people recommended to use Foundation to replicate the visuals of that website.

Where I'm having problems is with the larger images that take two rows (essentially).

I started to see if I can do it with Foundation but I'm stuck, I have been reading the documentation and the Grid section doesn't seem to have something that will allow an image to fill two rows while preserving the state of the following images for the 2nd row.

Yeah, it's a lot of talking, let me show some code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-3 columns">
      <img src="http://www.nevrisfurs.com/sites/all/themes/custom/nevris/images/home-company.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="small-3 columns">
      <img src="http://www.nevrisfurs.com/sites/all/themes/custom/nevris/images/home-news.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="small-6 columns">
      <img src="http://www.nevrisfurs.com/sites/all/themes/custom/nevris/images/home-collection-2014.jpg" >
  </div>
</div> <!-- /first row -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
      <img src="http://www.nevrisfurs.com/sites/all/themes/custom/nevris/images/home-video.jpg">
    </div>
</div> <!-- /second row -->
```

As you can see, the second row image is shown below the large image. Is there anyway to make it look like in the website that I mentioned?

Thank you!

P.S: I have modified the row class in foundation.css to have max-width: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

You Used row wise change to column wise, Use the below code

```
<style>
img {width:100%; height:auto}
</style>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-6 columns"><!-- /first Column -->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class=" small-6 columns">
                      <img src="http://www.nevrisfurs.com/sites/all/themes/custom/nevris/images/home-company.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="small-6 columns">
                      <img src="http://www.nevrisfurs.com/sites/all/themes/custom/nevris/images/home-news.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="small-12 columns" >
                      <img src="http://www.nevrisfurs.com/sites/all/themes/custom/nevris/images/home-video.jpg">
                  </div>
              </div><!-- /end first Column -->
          </div>
          <div class="small-6 columns" ><!-- /second Column -->
              <img src="http://www.nevrisfurs.com/sites/all/themes/custom/nevris/images/home-collection-2014.jpg" >
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya you can do it with foundation default classes..

Foundation is a `column based grid structure`..try organizing them in columns and fit them in rows.

so there are two columns of equal widths one having `three pics` second one with `one large pic`.

the `first column` has `two rows` one with `two pics` of equal widths `6-columns each` and second row with one large pic of `12 columns`

```css
.row{
max-width:none !important;  /* dosent work with out !importantfor snippet. Order of css is messed up with snippet */
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.4.7/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 columns">
          <img src="http://www.nevrisfurs.com/sites/all/themes/custom/nevris/images/home-company.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
          <img src="http://www.nevrisfurs.com/sites/all/themes/custom/nevris/images/home-news.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
         <img src="http://www.nevrisfurs.com/sites/all/themes/custom/nevris/images/home-video.jpg">
       </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
  <div class="large-6 columns">
      <img src="http://www.nevrisfurs.com/sites/all/themes/custom/nevris/images/home-collection-2014.jpg" >
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: ps: watch snippet in full screen